# Playframework: Handling Form Submission

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I am working on a Play 2.2 Form application. I create a form using this function

```
public static Result editIndicator() {
        Indicators addIndObj = new Indicators();
        addIndObj.aDt = (new Date()).toString();
        addIndObj.aUid = Long.parseLong(play.mvc.Controller.session("userid"));
        addIndObj.dTag = "N";

        // List of all Countries
        ALLCommon table_listobj = Indicators.ddl1();

        Form<Indicators> newIndicatorForm = form(Indicators.class).fill(
                addIndObj);

        return (ok(addindicator.render(newIndicatorForm, table_listobj)));

    }
```

the Indicator Model has parameters with constraints `@Required` for the parameters as follows

```
@Constraints.Required
@Column(name = "A_DT")
    public String aDt;
@Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "A_UID")
    public Long aUid;
@Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "D_TAG")
    public String dTag;
@Column(name = "TIME")
    @Required
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
    public Date time;
@Constraints.Required
    @Column(name = "INDFREQUENCY")
    public String indFrequency;
```

So, I set the values before and then bind it to form. I don't use all of these `@Required` values (just the Frequency part) in my form and when I try to get the filledform I get form errors

```
Form(of=class models.Indicators, 
data={}, value=None,
errors={time=[ValidationError(time,error.required,[])], 
aDt=[ValidationError(aDt,error.required,[])], 
dTag=[ValidationError(dTag,error.required,[])], 
aUid=[ValidationError(aUid,error.required,[])], 
indFrequency=[ValidationError(indFrequency,error.required,[])]})
```

Do I need to set these values in form even if I don't use it? Or I am missing something..
Any help is appriciated.. thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer..

1) You have to use all parameters that are required for your model i.e `@Required` and if you don't have to use it in your form. Simply put it in a `<div display:none>` tag.

2) On Submit button we call the `@forms(routes.Application.index)` but, the brackets should encapsulate your complete code and not just around the `submit` button. Hence,
 the best practice would be `@forms(routes.Application.index){ your complete code here}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups if you don't need to validate all fields all the time.

For example:

```
// interfaces to create groups
public interface Step1 {}
public interface Step2 {}
```

So you need to add thats groups to your fields:

```
@Required(groups = {Step1.class})
@Column(name = "A_DT")
public String aDt;

@Required(groups = {Step1.class})
@Column(name = "A_UID")
public Long aUid;

@Required(groups = {Step1.class})
@Column(name = "D_TAG")
public String dTag;

@Column(name = "TIME")
@Required(groups = {Step2.class})
@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
public Date time;

@Required(groups = {Step2.class})
@Column(name = "INDFREQUENCY")
public String indFrequency;
```

Then:

```
// this only validates the fields that have Step1 group (aDt, aUid, dTag in this example)
Form<Indicators> newIndicatorForm = form(Indicators.class, Step1.class)
        .fill(addIndObj);

// this only validates the fields that have Step2 group (time, indFrequency in this example)
Form<Indicators> newIndicatorForm = form(Indicators.class, Step2.class)
        .fill(addIndObj);

// this validates the fields of both groups (all the fields in this example)
Form<Indicators> newIndicatorForm = form(Indicators.class, Step1.class, Step2.class)
        .fill(addIndObj);
```